# How can I patch the source code of a folder?

Tags: ubuntu, patch, ppp

Well, here is the case, I learned that ubuntu dist has added some modification to the source of ppp source, 
which is here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/ppp

It seems ppp_2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.diff.gz is some patches for the source code, how can I patch it to the original source folder?
I tried something like patch -R, but I failed. the code remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded both the source code https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ppp_2.4.5.orig.tar.gz and patch file ppp_2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.diff.gz from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/ppp. And it is successfully patched no issues.

The patch file contains the diff file ppp_2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.diff. Please use the below command after unzipping the patch file ppp_2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.diff.gz and move it to the ppp-2.4.5 source code.

$ patch -p1 < ppp_2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.diff